# jQuery performance (query waste)

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

In legacy projects I used to load *all* jquery custom code in one doc.ready in one file on every page (easy to maintain, but lots of un-needed selectors per page). I started to think (a) this is messy programming anf (b) this must be bad performance, so I started to do some research.

I basically wanted one js file but wanted to only load/serve the queries/selectors/functions that were needed by that page.

I have come across 2 options:

1. http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#eliminate-query-waste

(script call at bottom of page above closing body tag

```
mylib.article.init();
```

global.js

```
var mylib =
{
    article_page :
    {
        init : function()
        {
            // Article page specific jQuery functions.
        }
    },
    traffic_light :
    {
        init : function()
        {
            // Traffic light specific jQuery functions.
        }
    }
}
```

2 . http://jonraasch.com/blog/5-performance-tuning-tricks-for-jquery

Suppose that in parts of a site we want to collapse side navigation elements on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sideNav LI:not(#current)').hide();
});
```

Even though some pages don’t have the side nav, this won’t throw an error in any browser, but let’s still make sure that the hide function only executes when it’s needed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sideNavPages = ['catalog', 'order', 'contact'];

    if ( jQuery.inArray(thisPage, sideNavPages) != -1 ) {
        $('#sideNav LI:not(#current)').hide();
    }
});
```

Which of the 2 above is better? Is there a third even better option?

Good to know what people think.

Adi.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a **lot** of jQuery code, you won't notice a performance difference; the DOM is optimized for finding elements, and as such is a relatively trivial operation (although, DOM manipulation is *one of* the slowest JavaScript operations you can do.

However, if you *have* identified a need for this, the approach I recommend is #1. One clever way to organise this is to have you JS organised such like;

```
var handlers = {
    id1: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });
    },

    id2: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });
    }
}
```

and then you can call your handler such as;

```
var id = $('body').attr('id');
if (id && typeof obj[id] == "function") {
    obj[id]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the two, I prefer the first one. On the other hand, I'd suggest you think about your desire to only have one JS file. If you separated out the code for each type of page, and then include just the one needed, you'd not only meet your requirement but also reduce your overall page size.

Anyway. All this is secondary to another thought, which is:

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"
>
> -- Donald Knuth

[Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) is a very wise man. Unless you feel that the number of selectors you're running is causing a noticeable problem, maybe you don't need to add any complexity to your code.